# How to dispatch value with join function in redux (react-native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I am having a state in redux store, I want to use function join() to join another value while dispatch but while using join() I get error join() is not a function.

```
var id = ['3','5']
dispatch({
 type: UPDATE,
 payload:{
  name: id.join();//this doesn't work
 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work. But I see a typo

```js
var id = ['3','5']
dispatch({
 type: UPDATE,
 payload:{
  name: id.join(),
 },
})
```

Comment: Sorry my bad if its an array, In my condition name is string in redux store and, id is an array. I will edit the question